# Add or remove a character at specified location in file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

For example, I've a text file having following lines (no. 423 and 424):

```
    //printf("%d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\n",i,c1,c2,c3,c11,c12,c21,c22,c31,c32); //testcells
    printf("%d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d   \n",i,r1,r2,r3,r11,r22,r33,r44,r55,r66,r77,r88,r99); //testnodes
```

Now, suppose I want to remove `//` in the 423<sup>th</sup> line i.e characters of column 5 and 6 form 423<sup>th</sup> line. And simultaneously, suppose I want to add `//` in 424<sup>th</sup> line in columns 5 and 6 such that expected output should be

```
    printf("%d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\n",i,c1,c2,c3,c11,c12,c21,c22,c31,c32); //testcells
    //printf("%d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d   \n",i,r1,r2,r3,r11,r22,r33,r44,r55,r66,r77,r88,r99); //testnodes
```

How do I do that? (preferably with `sed` or `awk`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
sed -e '423s!//!!; 424s!printf!//&!' < input > output
```

This assumes that the first `//` on line 423 is the one you want to remove, and that it's the `printf` on line 424 that you want to comment out.

To specifically update based on the columns:

```
sed -e '423s!^\(....\)//!\1!; 424s!^\(....\)!\1//!' < input > output
```